# Node Js hello world Program is not being displayed in localhost

Tags: node.js, localhost

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 3000

app.get('/', (req, res) => {
  res.send('Hello World!')
})

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}`)
})
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OiQq5.png) CMD

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UOSYz.png) local host

I need to run node js successfully and see the hello world output on local host

Answer (score 0):

That code seems to be OK.

Please try http://127.0.0.1:3000

Or try to move your project to different folder, I see it is placed in One Drive folder ? Maybe some permission issue ?

I hope you also tried restart your machine if you just installed NodeJS before trying this out.

Comment: I tried using different location, it didn't work